# MyScrollView doesn't respond to touch when I pass the touch event to superview

Tags: iphone, delegates, uiscrollview, protocols, touch

I have a ViewController with ScrollView SubView and those subview has a subview in it, below is the hierarchy :

AppDelegate - MyViewController - ScrollView(from xib) - MyScrollViewSubClass

// MyViewController :
// .h

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController<MyScrollViewSubClassDelegate,UIScrollViewDelegate> {
    UIScrollView            *scrollView; // Loaded from xib 
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

@end
```

// .m

```
@implementation MyViewController

@synthesize scrollView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    scrollView.delegate = self;

    MyScrollViewSubClass *myScrollView = [[MapScrollView alloc] init];
    myScrollView.delegate = self;
    myScrollView.myDelegate = self;

    scrollView addSubview:mapScrollView];
}

// The MyScrollViewSubClassDelegate @required method

- (void) onDoubleTapLocation: (CGPoint)tapPoint
{
    // Working,,,NSLog shown that this line is Working... 
}
```

// MyScrollViewSubClass + Delegate
// .h

```
// Protocol
@protocol MyScrollViewSubClasswDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void) onDoubleTapLocation: (CGPoint)tapPoint;
@end

//Interface

@protocol MyScrollViewSubClass;

@interface MyScrollViewSubClass : UIScrollView <UIScrollViewDelegate> {
    id <MyScrollViewSubClasswDelegate> myDelegate;

    // Another vars..   
}

@property (nonatomic,assign) id<MyScrollViewSubClasswDelegate> myDelegate;

- (void)handleDoubleTap;

@end
```

// .m

```
@implementation MyScrollViewSubClass
@synthesize myDelegate;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {

        // Another Code Here...

        self.delegate = self; // delegate for UIScrollView
        self.myDelegate = self;

        //Another Code Here...

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   if(isDoubleTap)
   {
      //Call handle double tap
      [self handleDoubleTap];
   }
}

- (void)handleDoubleTap {
    [self.myDelegate onDoubleTapLocation: tapLocation];
}
```

What Happen is the double tap is working on MyViewController, but now i can't scroll and pinch  zoom my  MyScrollViewSubClass from MyViewController, any critics, comment or better method are welcome..

**Resolved :**

I assign delegate on *MyViewController* twice

was :

```
myScrollView.delegate = self;
myScrollView.myDelegate = self;
```

Should be :

```
myScrollView.myDelegate = self;
```

Regards,

Ferry Hattawidian

Comment: how is `isDoubleTap` set? Also, clarify your last sentence, I suspect you meant "but I can't scroll and pinch my ..." is that accurate?

Comment: Yes thats my typo.. my check that the touch is double tap or single tap by counting the touches --> if ([touches count] == 2) { isDoubleTap = YES;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Resolved :**

I assign delegate on MyViewController twice

was :

```
myScrollView.delegate = self; 
myScrollView.myDelegate = self;
```

Should Be :

```
myScrollView.myDelegate = self;
```

Everything else is running well... Thanks guys...